# What is a good alternative for "Date" when talking about range of years?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, dates

I need to design a table where one of the columns is the range of years. The range of years denote when someone was working in a specific city. For example,

```
Date       Location
---------  --------
1990-1992  London
1992-1996  Boston
```

"Date" looks odd to me because the column values do not appear to be dates but rather year ranges.

Is there a better word for the column header? A few things that came to mind were, "Duration", "Years", "When", etc. but I don't know if there is a standard word for this that is suitable for this.

Comment: *time-interval*, *period*...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the OP refers to as "The **range of years** denote when someone was working in a specific city" is a typical example of a ***period***.

**[period](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/period)** (Lexico)
noun

> **1A** length or portion of time.
>   …
>     ‘the period 1977–85’
>   …
>     ‘The file dates span the period between September 1996 and April 1997.’

Answer (score 1):

[**Term**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/term)

> a limited or definite extent of time

**[Tenure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenure)** and **[duration](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duration)** are synonyms and are equally as valid.

Comment: Why did at last two people down-vote this?

Comment: @puppetsock you would not believe the pettiness of people on this site.  They actually look for my other answers to downvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

*Timespan* would be an succinct, unambiguous term.
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/timespan